# Change property of element <a> in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I bulid the folliwing nav.

```
<ul class="topnav">
        <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let index = index">
          <a (click)='onClick($event)' [class.active]="index == 0" routerLink="{{ menuItem.link }}">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

At the start first  in underlined.(css)

```
ul.topnav li a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #27ae60;
}
```

I have added method onClick in element 
I defined this method in typescript file in class corresponding with this html with

```
onClick(someobject): void {
      someobject.target.attributes['class'].value = "active";
      console.log(someobject);
    }
```

However the class active does not apped to selected  element. What is more how to clear mark class active from previous  element?

Comment: `[attr.class]="{ index === 0: 'active'}">` maybe?

Comment: @Z.Bagley Where should it be putted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `routerLinkActive` directive. Option {exact:true} is needed if your route is also part of another route.

```
<a routerLink="dashboard" 
   routerLinkActive="active" 
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
>Dashboard</a>
```

Ref: [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)

**Footnote**
Add the directive to every anchor tag in the Nav, it will take care of adding and removing.

Comment: How about removing? Should I add to method some other parameter?

Comment: It should be sufficient to put the directive on every `<a>`, it will adjust them all for you.